# How to fix unreliable wireless with DD-WRT

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I have a [Netgear WNDR4500](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/WNDR4500.aspx) running [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index). I have a couple desktops wired to it, which have never had any networking problems associated with the router. I also have 2.4GHz Wi-Fi with AES encryption enabled on it, and it’s always been unreliable.

One moment, it’ll work fine from a laptop or cell phone, then the next it’ll be completely unresponsive, even though signal strength is near 100%. When it’s unresponsive, I’ll connect a laptop to the router with an ethernet cable, and the Internet will work fine and the admin interface will be accessible showing no problems.

How do I diagnose the problem with DD-WRT’s wireless support and fix it? All my settings are pretty vanilla. DD-WRT’s status screen shows memory usage isn’t even over 50% so I don't think the problem is caused by low resources or excessive heavy-usage.

I tried configuring it to reboot once a day at midnight, but that had no effect.

Comment: Have you tried a different channel?

Comment: Does the stock firmware also have this problem?